# pymxs alternatives to the deprecated MaxPlus utility functions

Tags: python, 3dsmax, maxscript, 3ds

With Autodesk's removal of MaxPlus from 3ds Max, I now am having to rework some of my code, and was wondering if there is another way to access some of the MaxPlus utility functions.  While I think the decision to consolidate python development under pymxs was a good one, it would have been nice if MaxPlus functionality not supported by pymxs had been ported over beforehand.

examples of deprecated MaxPlus utility functions that I now need to find solutions for:

```
MaxPlus.ViewportManager.GetActiveViewportShowEdgeFaces()
MaxPlus.PathManager.GetProjectFolderDir()
MaxPlus.PathManager.GetAutobackDir()
```

Any help pointing me in the right direction, would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most of the viewport functionality is located in the NitrousGraphicsManager class, so for your first one, try:

```
>>> graphicsmanager = 
pymxs.runtime.NitrousGraphicsManager.GetActiveViewportSetting()
>>> graphicsmanager.ShowEdgedFacesEnabled
False
>>> graphicsmanager.ShowEdgedFacesEnabled = True
```

The second one you can find in the pathconfig struct:

```
pymxs.runtime.pathconfig.getCurrentProjectFolderPath()
```

The third is stored as a 3ds Max system directory, so this should work:

```
>>> pymxs.runtime.GetDir(pymxs.runtime.name('autoback'))
```